# kohana 3 creating routes with get

Tags: php, kohana

This has to do with routing. So for getting parameters via url, you basically pass the data to the url following the route format you set.

This is working with links. I created the route, passed the data into the url, and used the request method to get the parameter for use in the controller. like `URL::site("site/$color/$size")`

What if I am constructing the url by form submission? For example, if I want to create a basic search query.

How do I get my form submission to look like this `search/orange/large` and not like this `search.php?color=orange&size=large` when I submit a form via get method.

Comment: When creating links from routes I prefer using `Route::get()->uri())`, this could look like `Route::get('fruits')->uri(array('color'=>$color,'size'=>$size))` in this example. The advantage of this method is that when a route changes, the links automatically changes (in you version you'd have to change every link manually after changing the route)

Answer (score 0):

By [definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), the [GET method](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html#tech) puts the submitted information as URL parameters. If you specifically want to end up with a URL like `site/$color/$size`, you can use the [POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

A partial example, from a controller on one of my sites (there is a submit button on the page named `clear_cache_button`):

```
public function action_index()
{
    $session = Session::instance();

    $is_post = (Request::current()->post('submit_button') !== NULL);
    $is_clear_cache = (Request::current()->post('clear_cache_button') !== NULL);

    $p = Database::instance()->table_prefix();
    $people = DB::query(Database::SELECT, "
            SELECT *
            FROM `".$p."Tabe`;
        ")->cached(600, $is_clear_cache)->execute()->as_array('RegID');

    if ($is_clear_cache)
    {
        HTTP::redirect(Request::current()->uri());
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Route filters](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters) (v3.3) or [callbacks](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic) (3.1, 3.2) and set route params manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way...

```
public function action_index()
  {
    // this will only be executed if you submmitted a form in your page
    if(Arr::get($_POST,'search')){
      $errors = '';

      $data = Arr::extract($_POST,array('color','size'));

      // you can now access data through the $data array:
      // $data['color'], $data['size']

      // perform validations here
      if($data['color']=='') $error = 'Color is required';
      elseif($data['size']=='') $error = 'Size is required';

      if($error==''){
        $this->request->redirect('search/'.$data['color'].'/'.$data['size']);
      }
    }


    // load your search page view here

    echo 'this is the search page';

  }
```

Hope this helps you out.